# How to load a json file with strings including double quotes (")

Tags: json, python-3.x, double-quotes

I've been given a load of JSON files which I'm trying to load into python 3.5

I've already had to do some clean up work, removing double backslashes and extra quotations, however I've run into an issue I don't know how to solve.

I'm running the following code:

```
with open(filepath,'r') as json_file:
    reader = json_file.readlines()
    for row in reader:
        row = row.replace('\\', '')
        row = row.replace('"{', '{')
        row = row.replace('}"', '}')
        response = json.loads(row)
        for i in response:
                responselist.append(i['ActionName'])
```

However it's throwing up the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 388833 (char 388832)
```

The part of the JSON that's causing the issue is the status text entry below:

```
"StatusId":8,
"StatusIdString":"UnknownServiceError",
"StatusText":"u003cCompany docTypeu003d"Mobile.Tile" statusIdu003d"421" statusTextu003d"Start time of 11/30/2015 12:15:00 PM is more than 5 minutes in the past relative to the current time of 12/1/2015 12:27:01 AM." copyrightu003d"Copyright Company Inc." versionNumberu003d"7.3" createdDateu003d"2015-12-01T00:27:01Z" responseIdu003d"e74710c0-dc7c-42db-b608-bf905d95d153" /u003e",
"ActionName":"GetTrafficTile"
```

I added the line breaks to illustrate my point, it looks like python is unhappy that the string contains double quotes.

I have a feeling this may be to do with my replacing '\ \' with '' messing with the unicode characters in the string. Is there any way to repair these nested strings? I don't mind if the StatusText field is deleted completely, all I'm after is a list of the ActionName fields.

EDIT:
I've hosted an example file here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1oanrneg3aqandz/2015-12-01T00%253A00%253A42.527Z_2015-12-01T00%253A01%253A17.478Z?dl=0

This is exactly as I received, before I've replaced the extra backslashes and quotations

Here is a pared down version of the sample with one bad entry

```
["{\"apiServerType\":0,\"RequestId\":\"52a65260-1637-4653-a496-7555a2386340\",\"StatusId\":0,\"StatusIdString\":\"Ok\",\"StatusText\":null,\"ActionName\":\"GetCameraImage\",\"Url\":\"http://mosi-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1/GetCameraImage?AuthToken=vo*AB57XLptsKXf0AzKjf1MOgQ1hZ4BKipKgYl3uGew%7C&CameraId=13782\",\"Lat\":0.0,\"Lon\":0.0,\"iVendorId\":12561,\"iConsumerId\":2986897,\"iSliverId\":51846,\"UserId\":\"2986897\",\"HardwareId\":null,\"AuthToken\":\"vo*AB57XLptsKXf0AzKjf1MOgQ1hZ4BKipKgYl3uGew|\",\"RequestTime\":\"2015-12-01T00:00:42.5278699Z\",\"ResponseTime\":\"2015-12-01T00:01:02.5926127Z\",\"AppId\":null,\"HttpMethod\":\"GET\",\"RequestHeaders\":\"{\\\"Connection\\\":[\\\"keep-alive\\\"],\\\"Via\\\":[\\\"HTTP/1.1 nycnz01msp1ts10.wnsnet.attws.com\\\"],\\\"Accept\\\":[\\\"application/json\\\"],\\\"Accept-Encoding\\\":[\\\"gzip\\\",\\\"deflate\\\"],\\\"Accept-Language\\\":[\\\"en-us\\\"],\\\"Host\\\":[\\\"mosi-prod.cloudapp.net\\\"],\\\"User-Agent\\\":[\\\"Traffic/5.4.0\\\",\\\"CFNetwork/758.1.6\\\",\\\"Darwin/15.0.0\\\"]}\",\"RequestContentHeaders\":\"{}\",\"RequestContentBody\":\"\",\"ResponseBody\":null,\"ResponseContentHeaders\":\"{\\\"Content-Type\\\":[\\\"image/jpeg\\\"]}\",\"ResponseHeaders\":\"{}\",\"MiniProfilerJson\":null}"]
```

Comment: If its json, you shouldn't have to remove anything. And if you've removed backslashes... aren't those the backslashes used to escape the quotes that are now causing you problems? json puts these annotations in on purpose. If you end up not liking the decoding, its likely a bug in whatever passed stuff to the json encoder.

Comment: How about posting an example json file so we can see for ourselves.

Comment: I've added a link to an example of the files I've recieved

Comment: Is the code in my answer what you are looking for, or did I have misunderstood something in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a little different than you think. Whatever program built these files used data that was already json-encoded and ended up double and even triple encoding some of the information. I peeled it apart in a shell session and got usable python data. You can (1) go dope-slap whoever wrote the program that built this steaming pile of... um... goodness? and (2) manually scan through and decode inner json strings.

I decoded the data and it was a list of strings, but those strings looked suspiciously like json

```
>>> data = json.load(open('test.json'))
>>> type(data)
<class 'list'>
>>> d0 = data[0]
>>> type(d0)
<class 'str'>
>>> d0[:70]
'{"apiServerType":0,"RequestId":"52a65260-1637-4653-a496-7555a2386340",'
```

Sure enough, I can decode it

```
>>> d0_1 = json.loads(d0)
>>> type(d0_1)
<class 'dict'>
>>> d0_1
{'ResponseBody': None, 'StatusText': None, 'AppId': None, 'ResponseTime': '2015-12-01T00:01:02.5926127Z', 'HardwareId': None, 'RequestTime': '2015-12-01T00:00:42.5278699Z', 'StatusId': 0, 'Lon': 0.0, 'Url': 'http://mosi-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1/GetCameraImage?AuthToken=vo*AB57XLptsKXf0AzKjf1MOgQ1hZ4BKipKgYl3uGew%7C&CameraId=13782', 'RequestContentBody': '', 'RequestId': '52a65260-1637-4653-a496-7555a2386340', 'MiniProfilerJson': None, 'RequestContentHeaders': '{}', 'ActionName': 'GetCameraImage', 'StatusIdString': 'Ok', 'HttpMethod': 'GET', 'iSliverId': 51846, 'ResponseHeaders': '{}', 'ResponseContentHeaders': '{"Content-Type":["image/jpeg"]}', 'apiServerType': 0, 'AuthToken': 'vo*AB57XLptsKXf0AzKjf1MOgQ1hZ4BKipKgYl3uGew|', 'iConsumerId': 2986897, 'RequestHeaders': '{"Connection":["keep-alive"],"Via":["HTTP/1.1 nycnz01msp1ts10.wnsnet.attws.com"],"Accept":["application/json"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip","deflate"],"Accept-Language":["en-us"],"Host":["mosi-prod.cloudapp.net"],"User-Agent":["Traffic/5.4.0","CFNetwork/758.1.6","Darwin/15.0.0"]}', 'iVendorId': 12561, 'Lat': 0.0, 'UserId': '2986897'}
```

Picking one of the entries, that looks like more json

```
>>> hdrs = d0_1['RequestHeaders']
>>> type(hdrs)
<class 'str'>
```

Yep, it decodes to what I want

```
>>> hdrs_0 = json.loads(hdrs)
>>> type(hdrs_0)
<class 'dict'>
>>> 
>>> hdrs_0["Via"]
['HTTP/1.1 nycnz01msp1ts10.wnsnet.attws.com']
>>> 
>>> type(hdrs_0["Via"])
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: If they were still with the company they'd be getting so many dope-slaps right now. The issue is I've got about 8000 of these files to look through, so manually scanning through strings is unfeasible. Could I set up a try statement to handle the exceptions by decoding a second time?

Comment: The files may follow a pattern and once you've figured one out, you've got them all. Otherwise, I'd do exactly what you are thinking. Walk through all the lists and dicts, test if values are strings, then try a `json.loads(value)`. You'll get a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` for strings that really should stay strings.

Comment: I've worked out that all the unreadable files were of a same actionName, and all I'm after is a count of the different response types. I set up a try loop that records the number of failures, and I'll append that to my results. I've marked this answer as correct for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are :) :

```
responselist = []
with open('dataFile.json','r') as json_file:
    reader = json_file.readlines()
    for row in reader:
        strActNm = 'ActionName":"'; lenActNm = len(strActNm)
        actionAt = row.find(strActNm)
        while actionAt > 0:
            nxtQuotAt = row.find('"',actionAt+lenActNm+2)
            responselist.append( row[actionAt-1: nxtQuotAt+1] )
            actionAt = row.find('ActionName":"', nxtQuotAt)
print(responselist)
```

which gives:

```
>python3.6 -u "dataFile.py"
['"ActionName":"GetTrafficTile"']
>Exit code: 0
```

where `dataFile.json` is the file with the line you provided and `dataFile.py` the code provided above.

It's the hard tour, but if the files are in a bad format you have to find a way around and a simple pattern matching works in any case. For more complex cases you will need regex (regular expressions), but in this  case a simple `.find()` is enough to do the job.

The code finds also multiple "actions" in the line (if the line would contain more than one action).

Here the result for the file you provided in your link while using following small modification of the code above:

```
responselist = []
with open('dataFile1.json','r') as json_file:
    reader = json_file.readlines()
    for row in reader:
        strActNm='\\"ActionName\\":\\"'
        # strActNm = 'ActionName":"'
        lenActNm = len(strActNm)
        actionAt = row.find(strActNm)
        while actionAt > 0:
            nxtQuotAt = row.find('"',actionAt+lenActNm+2)
            responselist.append( row[actionAt: nxtQuotAt+1].replace('\\','') )
            actionAt = row.find('ActionName":"', nxtQuotAt)
print(responselist)
```

gives:

```
>python3.6 -u "dataFile.py"
['"ActionName":"GetCameraImage"']
>Exit code: 0
```

where dataFile1.json is the file you provided in the link.